# Play! Framework + DynamoDB

Tags: amazon-web-services, playframework, amazon-dynamodb

Being new with the Play Framework, I'm wondering if it's easier than I think, but is it possible to use DynamoDB with the Play Framework?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As DynamoDB is a NoSQL database, I expect that you would need to use a specific module, which as Dynamo was only recently announced, a module does not exist.

If you are interested in writing your own module, then using Mongo (http://www.playframework.org/modules/mongo-1.3/home) as a starting point (also NoSQL), will give you a good guide on how this has been achieved in other implementations.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use DynamoDB with this library https://github.com/seratch/AWScala It seems to be pretty well